# Prevent "Clipboard re-direction" on Windows Server 2016 for Users groups

Tags: windows-server-2016

I got this problem as i tried to figure out how to enable/disable "Clipboard redirection" action on Windows Server 2016.
Be default, this policy is set as No Configuration.
If i enable or disable this policy, it would apply to every user in system including Administrator group (2 user) and some other user in Users group. (20 users)
But i just want to apply this to only Admin groups. OF course, i can apply to each user but that would take a lot of time. If i have 1000 users that way is not efficient. 
Would you mind helping me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Fine-grained policy management requires Active Directory. If you don't have AD and are just configuring policies locally, there's nothing you can do. And if you have 1000 users, you *really* should set up AD at this point.

If you haven't done so already, put this policy in a *separate* Group Policy object (ruleset). That is, don't put miscellaneous stuff in the default domain policy. Open up "Group Policy Management" and use it to manage rulesets.

Once you have a separate policy ruleset, there are several ways to limit it:

- If you have separate AD folders (OUs) for users and admins, then just link the policy object under the appropriate folder instead of the whole domain.
- If you want to use groups, then use "Security Filtering" to assign users and groups which the policy object should apply to.

There are probably other ways in Server 2016...

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually the number of user is not that much, about 30 users. But i just want to find a quickest way to do this. And our customer don't require Active Directory. I've come up the idea of disable for every user and then use Snap-in to enable for 2 admin user.